# SharePoint 2010 Search - Site Collection - Managed Paths

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, search-scope

I am having issues getting search to work in a Site Collection that is in a managed path. My site structure is as below:

Publishing Site

---Managed Path

-----Site Collection

The search is working on the Publishing site, but how do I get the search to work from within the Site Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the load balancer that we are behind did not have NAT enabled.  Once that was enabled that seemed to have resolved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

How is it not working?  When searching in a site collection typically it will only returns results from that site collection.

Do you have a search center created?  Is your site collection configured to use that search center?

Comment: No results are returned.  Is the search center specific to that site collection?  If so, I don't have a search center created.  The main site search is working.

Comment: The search center is a seperate site collection, and then in your site collection's search settings, you enable custom scopes and put in the path to the pages library of your search center.